# Is such difference between mingw and msvc normal

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, mingw

Today we found a bug at work, which can be simplified to this:

```
std::map<int, Obj*> workMap;

for(auto a : workMap)
{
    workMap.erase(a.first);
}
```

Actually, we invoked function, that invoked function that did erase, but it is not the point.

The point is, that on my computer with visual studio compiler I've got **list iterator is not incrementable error**, while my colleague with mingw has got no errors at all!

I understand, that we have different compilers and different implementations of STL(probably). It is normal, that they could have different warnings or flags to suppress warnings. But it is different runtime error behaviour. Is this normal? And can I somehow "enable" all runtime errors?

Comment: Undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: +1 for providing an sscce :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These types of for-loops are not for changing the container itself. You invalidate iterators you still use, thus anything can happen. Since this is undefined behavior, the compiler is allowed to generate code that does *anything*, there are no guarantees what so ever, so both compilers are correct.

Your observation is caused by the fact that msvc enables some runtime checking for debug builds by default, gcc does not.

You can enable runtime checking for `libstd++`, the standard library implementation of gcc, with `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC` during compilation. It will show an error in your example. ([Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3a62554b2a89861))

Comment: It's worth noting that if you interface with any c++ libraries, those libraries must also be built with those flags set. The ABI of libstdc++ changes when you enable those flags.

Comment: @sharth: generally speaking you're right, but in this particular case, being std::map is a template, it has noting to link coming from other translation units, so it works.

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia: I was more referring to passing the whole `std::map` or `std::map::iterator` to another translation unit that wasn't compiled with the flags.

Answer (score 2):

Just so we're all clear, this code:

```
std::map<int, Obj*> workMap
for(auto a : workMap)
    workMap.erase(a.first);
```

causes undefined behavior and should **not** be expected to work properly.

Visual Studio is simply being helpful and providing a runtime error about this. It's not obligated to do this.